# Is there a very verbose output for ld linker? (linker crashing silently)

Tags: gcc, ld

I have an issue with a complex **embedded** project, compiling/linking with GCC 12.2.0 from mingw64. There are cases in which the `ld` linker (version 2.39) **crashes without any message** or file output.

I've spotted a command line option that causes the event, but I have no clue what happens.

The project is comprised of some C modules, compiled individually and linked statically at a very specific base address.
The compiler operation for each source, called from a batch file, looks like this

```
set CCOPT=-g3 -O2 -c -gstabs
set CCOPT=%CCOPT% -Wno-builtin-declaration-mismatch
set CCOPT=%CCOPT% -Wall -Wextra
set CCOPT=%CCOPT% -march=i386 -pedantic 
set CCOPT=%CCOPT% -fno-builtin -ffreestanding 
set CCOPT=%CCOPT% -fno-ident
gcc main.c -o .\out\main.o %CCOPT%
```

and the final link looks like this

```
set OBJFILES=main.o ...

set LDOPT=
set LDOPT=%LDOPT% -static
set LDOPT=%LDOPT% --image-base=0xD00020
set LDOPT=%LDOPT% --section-alignment=0x20 --file-alignment=0x20
set LDOPT=%LDOPT% -mi386pe -nostdlib -L .\out -Map=file.map
set LDOPT=%LDOPT% -o .\out\file.ext
ld %LDOPT% %OBJFILES%
```

When all is well, I have my output file. When something *is wrong* the linker hangs for a while (from one second to a few tens). The result is no stderr/stdout messages, and all output files are truncated to zero length.

What decides *right* or *wrong* is the addition/removal of a few C lines (changing the compiled size?) in some modules. Note that with compilation all is well, I can successfully disassemble object files, source files have been validated by a few analyzers (CppCheck, Clang, besides the same GCC).

The offending option is `--image-base` and it's not related only to the value `0xD00020` above, I tried different boundaries (and I don't have many choices, due to the embedded system memory layout), but I can say it happens sometimes with `0xD00100` and `0xD00200` too.

I tried to cut a short example of code to attach here, but unfortunately, it's a too large code base, and I didn't reproduce it with a small set.

- How can I ask for more details from the `ld` operation? If that is possible, even though I suspect the crash is also trashing any open file
- Are there any known issues in image base redefinition?

*Note: the test has been run in two very different environments, a VM Windows XP pro x86, and a native Windows 11 pro x64.*

**[EDIT]**

As of today, the problem persists **only** with a specific setup: using the distribution [w64devkit](https://github.com/skeeto/w64devkit), even with older releases.

I tried in fact some other linkers provided as binary executables of GNU `ld`, though from **different sources**, and the problem disappeared.

Using `ld` from [mingw-builds-binaries](https://github.com/niXman/mingw-builds-binaries) version 12.2.00 (linker version 2.39 as before) all worked smoothly.

Even using the `ld` from [Code::Blocks](https://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/binaries/) version 20.03 (linker version 2.30) everything works - *note that this toolkit seemingly uses the mingw-builds-binaries said above, from a very older compiler set (GCC 8.1.0)*.

I'm suspecting then an issue with the **w64devkit** linker. Unfortunately, I don't have any additional details for this claim.

Comment: Can you run the link command under a debuger, say, `gdb`? Then you can see which signal happens and maybe look at a stack backtrace for better diagnosis.

Comment: @Jens this adds more fun. I extracted only a *crashing* partial link phase and running it from the command line it crashes as already seen. Then I run it with `gdb --args ld [a lot of stuff]` and it runs to completion with `[Inferior 1 (process 1924) exited normally]`, creating all the output files!

Comment: The only provided insight so far is from the Win XP VM, where now I can get an exception **0xc0000005**, an access violation - that unfortunately doesn't happen when running the same command in `gdb`

Comment: Fun with heisenbugs; they change under observation :-)

Comment: My guess is that some block of allocated memory is used without proper initialization, so the launcher/allocator makes the difference. Maybe the byte in the box is alive, maybe not, but I'm not gonna put my fingers in to find ;^)